# multiple useQuery giving the same data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have two useQuery hooks to get data:

const {isLoading, error, data} = useQueryStudent(id_x);
const {isLoading: isLoading2, error: error2, data: data2} = useQueryStudent(id_y)

but both data and data2 are giving me the same value for student(id_x), how do i get it so that data2 give me its intended value which is different from data?

I also tried this, but it doesn't also work

```
const queryMultiple = () => {
    const res1 = useQueryStudent(id_x)
    const res2 = useQueryStudent(id_y)

    return [res1, res2]
  }

      const [
        { isLoading: isLoading1,
          error: error1,
          data: data1, },
        { isLoading: isLoading2,
          error: error2,
          data: data2, }
      ] = queryMultiple()
```

```
this is my useQueryStudent:

function useQueryStudent(studentId) {
  const queryKey = ["student"];
  const { token, updateToken } = useStoreToken();

  const getStudent = async () => {
    try {
      const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
      const endpoint = `${BASE_URL}/api/student/${studentId}`;
      const res = await axios.get(endpoint, { headers });
      const { message, data, token: newToken } = res.data;
      debug({ message, data });
      updateToken(newToken);
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      debug({ err });
      showNotification({
        title: "Oh no!",
        message: getMessage(err),
        color: "red",
        icon: <TbX />,
      });
      throw err;
    }
  };

  return {
    ...useQuery(queryKey, getStudent, {
      fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    }),
  };
}
```

```
     useEffect(() => {
    if (data1) {
      setStudentAData(data1);
    }
    }, [data1]);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data2) {
          setPlayerBData(data2);
        }
      }, [data2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to see how you implemented `useQueryStudent`, but I think the issue here is that because both queries are sharing the same query key so the second query returns the data from the first query in the cache. To resolve this you need to provide each query with its unique query key:

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQueryStudent(id_x, {
  queryKey: ['student', id_x], // Provide a unique key for this query
});
```

```
const { isLoading: isLoading2, error: error2, data: data2 } = useQueryStudent(id_y, {
  queryKey: ['student', id_y], // Provide a unique key for this query
});
```

Comment: source: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-keys

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have added my useQueryStudent in the question.

Comment: the issue with `queryKey`, you should update it to: `const queryKey = ["student", studentId];`

Comment: I now am having issues with the usEffect for it, when data changes, the useffect is no longer getting called

Comment: I have edited and added the useEffects in the question

Comment: Can you create a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: i fixed it with the change of the querykey you gave me. Thanks!